# What are the consequences when large-sample asymptotics does not hold?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, asymptotics, frequentist, wald-test

Lots of (frequentist) statistical inference is based on large-sample asymptotics.

**What are the specific consequences when a sample size is not big enough for the sampling distribution of an estimator to be approximated using the asymptotic sampling distribution?**

The confidence interval will not have proper coverage, but will it be too wide or too narrow?

Comment: Can be too wide, too narrow, or a mixture of both, sometimes a complicated mixture of both. For one example pertaining to asymptotics on Bernouli see the simulation presented in  Agresti, A. and Coull, B. A. (1998). [Approximate is better than “exact” for interval estimation of binomial proportions](http://www.math.unm.edu/~james/Agresti1998.pdf). *The American Statistician*, 52(2):119–126.

Comment: @Alexis I think that's basically an answer, maybe with a bit more detail. Do you want to write it?

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica Thank you for the encouragement. I also welcome any guidance on my answer, now posted.

Answer (score 1):

**Asymptotic confidence intervals on 'small' samples can have wider than nominal coverage, narrower than nominal coverage, or a mixture of both… sometimes a complicated mixture of both wider and narrower coverage.**

(This is a broad question, so this answer is similarly broad.)

The particulars of wider vs narrower vs a mixture of both will depend on the specific distribution and the sample size in question, as well as by the specific form of CI. As one example, Figure 4 from Agresti & Coull (1998) below illustrates the empirical coverage probabilities based on simulations using two asymptotic CIs (left and center), and the exact CI (right) for a proportion (the $p$ of a Bernoulli distribution) at sample sizes 5 and 10.

[image: Figure 4. Agresti and Coull, 1998]

As you can see, the Wald CI produces narrower than nominal coverage for virtually all values of $p$, the adjusted Wald CI appears to have less bias than the Wald CI when averaged across all values of $p$, but has a mixture, and the exact ('non-asymptotic') has strictly wider coverage. Also of note is the heterogeneous patterning of the biases across values of $p$.

So the answer is in effect *it depends*.